# Wamp server: Using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I'm working with sql through wamp server, however whenever I try to open phpmyadmin from the localhost I get this error: 
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

What's the reason for this error? Is it the wamp server itself, or my machine? and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Change the file content of c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf to the following.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here my WAMP installation is in the c:\wamp folder. Change it according to your installation.

Previously, it was like this:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Restart your Apache server after making these changes.